# iOS Facebook web share api - how to tell if the user has hit skip

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, error-handling

I have a VC with a button hooked up to do a facebook share of some text and an image url.

I use the FB api which opens the FB webview - for the user to login. It then presents the share window with a "Skip" or "Share" button as shown...

[image]

I have in my app the following code to take care of the login and button actions ....
For some reason the "Skip" also posts as if the "OK" was hit. I tried cheking thr error code returned using the Error Utility but that does not work (app never gets into that section of code and "CANCELLED OUT" is never logged in NSLog, even when I hit the Skip button)

Any help with this will be most appreciated. Perhaps some way to recheck permissions?

```
(void)postStatusUpdate:(id)status
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state != FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded || [FBSession.activeSession.permissions
                                                                              indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // Permission hasn't been granted, so ask for publish_actions
        [FBSessionopenActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                        allowLoginUI:YES
                        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, 
                                            NSError *error) {
                             [selfsessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

                              if([FBErrorUtilityerrorCategoryForError:error] ==
FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled)
                              {
                                   NSLog(@"SNFacebookClient: CANCELLED OUT!!");
                              }
                              if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen && !error) {
                                   // Publish the story if permission was granted
                                   [selfpublishStory:status];
                              }
         }];
    } else {
        // If permissions present, publish the story
        [selfpublishStory:status];
    }
}
```

code here

I even tried in lldb to check the permissions array after "Skip" was pressed ...

```
po [FBSession activeSession].permissions
```

And find that even when skip is pressed the array contains the entry "publish_actions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the session status, if the status is `FBSessionStateOpen` or `FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded`, you can fetch user's data.
Otherwise, something wrong happen or user skipped it.

This approach is different of you, check my short comments to you understand the steps.

```
    // Suppose my FBSession is stored in a property called session
    @property (nonatomic, strong) FBSession *session;

    // The session getter can be implemented like this

    - (FBSession *)session
    {
        if(!_session)
        {
            _session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:readPermissions];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:_session];
        }

        return _session;
    }



    // Opening a new session 
    [self.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            [self session:session stateChanged:status error:error];
        }];


    - (void)session:(FBSession *)session stateChanged:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error
    {
        switch(state)
        {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
            {
                // Connection accepted
            }
            break;

            case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
            {
                // Connection restored
            }
            break;

            case FBSessionStateClosed:
                // Connection closed
                break;

            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            {
                // Connection failed and closed
            }
            break;

            case FBSessionStateCreated:
            {
                // Session created (not opened yet)
            }
            break;

            case FBSessionStateCreatedOpening:
                // Handler it if you need to do something while connection is opening
                break;

            case FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended:
                // Session token extended
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jan! I will try this and let you know if it works

Comment: your note says "if the status is FBSessionStateOpen or FBSessionStateOpen, you can fetch user's data" - was that a typo? It appears you recommend checking for two possible states but you've listed the same one two times (FBSessionStateOpen)